# web application structure hierarcy problem

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate.cfg.xml

Below an illustration of my project hierarchy

[image: project hierarchy]
<sub>(source: [yfrog.com](http://a.yfrog.com/img809/3151/58400945.png))</sub>

When i try to connect my file_name.java file to hibernate i'm getting these errors

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not instantiate cache implementation
    at org.hibernate.cache.CacheFactory.createCache(CacheFactory.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1218)
    at net.pkg.dao.FirstExample.main(FirstExample.java:17)
Caused by: org.hibernate.cache.NoCachingEnabledException: Second-level cache is not enabled for usage [hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache | hibernate.cache.use_query_cache]
    at org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider.buildCache(NoCacheProvider.java:21)
    at org.hibernate.cache.CacheFactory.createCache(CacheFactory.java:61)
```

the problem has something to do with my `hibernate.cfg.xml`... but I'm unable to resolve it. Any ideas?

Comment: Not that I would know how to resolve the problem but what strikes me is that you seem to be trying to load  cache implementation without having caching enabled...

Comment: i am getting same error in my project. you have any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you are using either `@Cacheable` or `@Cache` on your entities without having the second level cache activated, hence the error message:

```
o.h.c.NoCachingEnabledException: Second-level cache is not enabled for usage ...
```

You need something like this in the `hibernate.cfg.xml` to use the second level cache (I'm using EHCache as cache provider here):

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</property>
```

Whether you really need the second level cache is another story.